# Can I travel to the US for a business trip with a visitor visa?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, business-travel

I applied for a B2 visa. My visa was stamped B1/B2. 
I travelled to the US a few times using my visa as a visitor. 
My company wanted to send me to the US on a business trip. 
Can I travel to US for a business trip with my visa?
Will I face any problems at the port of entry?

Answer (score 5):

According to the US consulate:

> Most applicants applying for a nonimmigrant visas are visitors for
>   business (B1) or tourism (B2). The two categories of visa are usually
>   issued together as a B1/B2 visa.

In other words, as your visa is B1/B2, it allows you to visit the USA for both business and pleasure, however note that

> "Business" does not mean gainful employment, but it does include a
>   wide range of business-related activities (meetings, trainings,
>   negotiations) for which you are not being paid in the United States.
>   You may also seek medical treatment or travel as a domestic/personal
>   employee.

That is, you can go on a business trip, but you are not allowed to work in the USA as a permanent employment location.

Here's a link to the [US consulate in India](http://newdelhi.usembassy.gov/types_of_visas/tourism-/-business.html), but the rules are the same in other countries.